# Mounting "/run" as noexec

Tags: mount, systemd

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Currently `/run` is mounted as a `tmpfs` without `noexec`:

```
mount | grep '/run '
  tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=...,nr_inodes=...,mode=755,inode64)

lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
  Release:        22.04
  Codename:       jammy

uname -a
  Linux example.com 5.15.0-1020-aws #24-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:04:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I assume it's setup via `systemd`, as a [API File System](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/)? But I'm not sure how/where it's configured.

There is no entry in `/etc/fstab`.

The servers I administer that use Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS already have `noexec` on `/run`. I don't remember doing this manually, so I wonder if this might be a change in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

---

As to why... I've got a script to check every folder writable by the `www-data` user is on a `noexec` mount. The theory being, if any of the hosted websites have a security vulnerability that allows an attacker to create a file on the disk in an arbitrary location (e.g. /run/lock/apache2/), then at least `noexec` might provide some protection (I know it does not stop an interpreter from executing).

Comment: Ubuntu 22 would be the Ubuntu Core 22 product as that is the only Ubuntu that uses a single digit version number. If this is not the case please EDIT and correct the info.

Comment: ok, has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

A [bug report for the systemd package in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1991661) has been reported based on this question.  The difference in mount options when boot initrdless is seen as a possible regression.

**original**

The `/run` mount is typically created by the *initramfs-tools* `init` script inside of the initramfs.  This is before things like systemd run.  The `/run` [mount persists](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/init?id=d5778b720986feba03df008bf6b0b40ceb111dff#n305) after the initramfs pivots to the real root filesystem.

The [mount command](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/init?id=d5778b720986feba03df008bf6b0b40ceb111dff#n246) in *initramfs-tools* includes the `noexec` mount option.

```
mount -t tmpfs -o "nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=${RUNSIZE:-10%},mode=0755" tmpfs /run
```

If you need to modify the mount arguments used by *initramfs-tools* then you can edit the `init` script locally at `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init` and rebuild the initramfs with the command

```
update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

You are launching an Ubuntu VM in AWS.  When Ubuntu boots in AWS it does so **initrdless**, and does not use the initramfs.  When the kernel boots **initrdless** the *initramfs-tools* script does not run.  Instead, the `/run` mount (and others) are created by systemd as defined [in this mount table entry](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/13a5ffa4777545ca18971bf23c6dfd12f005eef2/src/shared/mount-setup.c#L87) and [these mount options](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/6f2cea06bfce6ad99f0ac37ab12af61ef7549fe3/src/shared/mount-util.h#L31).  The mount options do not appear to be customizable.  The resulting equivalent mount command is

```
mount -t tmpfs -o "nodev,nosuid,strictatime,size=20%,nr_inodes=800k,mode=0755" tmpfs /run
```

Based on [comment 21 in this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/livecd-rootfs/+bug/1870189) these commands update the AWS VM so it will boot with the initramfs instead of booting **initrdless**.

```
mv /etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg{,.bak}
update-grub
```

That same comments provides this insight on why the AWS VM boots **initrdless**.

> we provide custom kernels for our cloud partners which have all the
> drivers needed to boot built in, loading an initrd is a waste of time
> at boot

The `/run/lock` mount mentioned in the other answer is always created by systemd.  This is because of a [Debian/Ubuntu specific patch](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/-/blob/71d9fe8aabd2e4af54f99dfa4f769719ed021d39/debian/patches/debian/Make-run-lock-tmpfs-an-API-fs.patch) to systemd that defines the mount for "historic reasons".  The mount options do not seem to be configurable either.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I assume this is an edit AWS made to the initramfs, which I assume is in `initrd.img-5.11.0-1022-aws`. As this is a binary file, I assume this is outside of my control (and need to pay Amazon $30 to raise a support ticket), or would something like `update-initramfs` be able to help?

Comment: Huh, it looks like [this has happened before, in 2014](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/73180).

Comment: I tested an AWS 22.04 machine and saw the same mount options you shared.  I found it is booting initrdless, so the initramfs-tools init script does not get used.  I don't know what creates the `/run` mount in this situation but I added a couple notes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. You're absolutely right, no idea how you managed to find that. I've added a note to the [AWS re:Post forum](https://repost.aws/questions/QUurFhA7b6QLyPciC4qMpIHg/not-using-noexec-with-run-mount-on-ec-2-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts), and will try to get Amazon to look at it (as it seems to be a problem on their end).

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd update. I have just been told by Amazon security team that they are looking into this (to respond within 5 days), so I'll probably not edit my init script just yet (chance of me breaking it, when I get the impression Amazon should be fixing this themselves)... as an aside, I am intrigued as to why Tenable marked this type of problem as [High severity](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/73180) (security hardening vs vulnerability)

Comment: I reworded the answer to cleanup the edits.  I don't see how Amazon can change the behavior.  I think this would have to be a systemd change.  It looks like a bug has been filed from this question with Ubuntu at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1991661

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you've done a fantastic job digging into this, I've learnt a lot. Amazon have replied today, and it looks like the bug report you've linked to will be the eventual answer. I know I'm being cheeky, but could you edit your answer so it starts with the link to that bug report (to show it's a bug)... I worry someone might be reading this as an instruction, and may start making these changes themselves, make a mistake, and might end up with a non-booting system. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Jammy AMIs come pre-configured with /run/lock mount and noexec.

```
# findmnt -l | grep noexec
/proc                                     proc                   proc       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys                                      sysfs                  sysfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/kernel/security                      securityfs             securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/dev/pts                                  devpts                 devpts     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
/run/lock                                 tmpfs                  tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64
/sys/fs/cgroup                            cgroup2                cgroup2    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot
/sys/fs/pstore                            pstore                 pstore     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/fs/bpf                               bpf                    bpf        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
/dev/mqueue                               mqueue                 mqueue     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/kernel/debug                         debugfs                debugfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/kernel/tracing                       tracefs                tracefs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/kernel/config                        configfs               configfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/sys/fs/fuse/connections                  fusectl                fusectl    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
/run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service none                   ramfs      ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700

# mount -l | grep run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=192760k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
none on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=192760k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/lxd.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=96380k,nr_inodes=24095,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming Adam, glad to know it's not just my account. In this case I have accepted the answer from Andrew, as they have really dug into the situation, but I appreciate the time you have taken to check this.